# How to give a specific user a read ONLY permission to a specific folder in Linux without root?

Tags: permissions, chmod, read-only, username

I want to give a specific user with the username `userA` permission to only read a folder that I created.
Every other post that I found says you should either create a new group, which I cannot because I do not have root permission. When I tried creating a group `groupadd class1` it displayed the following message:

```
   groupadd: Permission denied.
   groupadd: cannot lock /etc/group; try again later
```

The other solution that was suggested by different posts is that I should make the user an owner of the folder, which I'm not comfortable doing because I do not want them adding others to the folder.

Comment: IIRC Ubuntu defaults to create groups for each user that is their username. IE username would be 'userA' and they'd have a group 'userA'. You could assign the file to the 'userA' group and give the file group permissions for read-only.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using ACLs (Access Control Lists).

`setfacl -m u:userA:rx folder`

if you want to give `userA` access to `folder` only (the user won't be able to read files within folder) or

`setfacl -R -m u:userA:rX folder`

if you want to give access to `folder` and all (already existing) files and subfolders within it.

Comment: I tried that and it displays the following `setfacl: class1/: Operation not supported`

Comment: what exact command did you use to get that response?

Comment: Is `class1` the folder in question? Are you the owner of it? If no, you cannot change permissions for that folder at all.

Comment: "Operation not supported" may also indicate that the filesystem does not support ACL or has been mounted without ACL option. In that case, only your admin can help.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you might really have TWO problems. But you also might not.

1. Your /home directory, the only place where a non-admin can reliably store files, has historically had a default setting of world-readable. EVERYBODY can already read all of your files...and write to (almost) none of them.

   ```
   $ ls -lah /home/
   total 16K
   drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4.0K Dec  3  2016 .
   drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4.0K Oct 16  2019 ..
   drwxr-xr-x 21 1001 1001 4.0K Aug 17  2017 susan
   drwxr-xr-x 45 me   me   4.0K Oct 20 15:30 me
   ```

   In this example, I can read (not write) to all of Susan's files, and she can read all of mine. I can also launch any of her applications and scripts. I can copy her files, and my copy (in my directory) will become writable by me (not her).

   If this setup is okay with you, then your problem is already solved: Your specific user already has read-only access.
2. If you convince your admin to lock down your /home directory so nobody can read your files anymore, it will look like this:

   ```
   $ ls -lah /home/
   total 16K
   drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4.0K Dec  3  2016 .
   drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4.0K Oct 16  2019 ..
   drwx--x--x 21 1001 1001 4.0K Aug 17  2017 susan
   drwx--x--x 45 me   me   4.0K Oct 20 15:30 me
   ```

   Now Susan cannot read my files anymore (nor I hers), and I must use a group to grant access to anybody else.

   You are completely right that only an admin can create a group, and only an admin can edit the members of that group.

   Step 1: You can change the permission of your own directories and files.

   Example:

   ```
   mkdir /home/me/public-view
   chmod 751 /home/me/public-view  // 7 means you have complete control over the directory
                                   // 5 means 'read-only' for members of the group
                                   // 1 means nobody outside you or the group can access it
                                   //  but it will still show up on directory listings
   ```

   Step 2: The admin creates a new group, adds Specific Person to that group, and changes the ownership of your directory so that the group (consisting of one person) can access it. Since you are the owner, you still have read/write access to everything in the dir (that's why you made sure you had permission '7' in the first column of chmod).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! The folder is not in my home directory and I did change the permission so no one can access it except me for now. If I convinced my admin to create a new group `class1` how do I specify which group can read the folder?

Comment: The admin must make that change: `sudo chown you:class1 /path/to/directory`. You are still the owner, but the group has been changed.